# Можно ли расширить список библиотек в Choose Library Dependencies Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Есть список библиотек, которые можно подключить с помощью `add library dependency` в `Android Studio`.
Можно ли расширить перечень библиотек? Или это нужно руками их добавлять?
Чтобы не добавлять их как `.jar` файлы или искать в сети, а они уже были в наборе библиотек.

У меня этот список выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не весь список. Просто наберите название нужной библиотеки и оно там появится.

[image: screen]

Поскольку поиск идет по Maven Central, то , думаю, нужное вы скорее всего найдете. Хорошим тоном считается выкладывать библиотеку именно туда. Интернет-соединение должно быть активно, так как поиск осуществляется в интернете.